# Common multiple SSH connections file handling issue

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

often I have to download a file that isn't directly accessable via the first SSH connection. For example I'm on a Windows machine and I want to access another machine that is only accessable from lan. That means that I must first connect to a intermediate machine and SSH to the next one.

It would be easy to use pscp to get the file, if it were available for the first machine. Could SSH port forwarding be used in this scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Just saying "reach them" leaves the obvious answer of ssh from one to the next. Do you want to SFTP instead? Do you want to setup a tunnel? Is it the ports that are blocked or the network that won't route or what are the connection limitations? (Please edit the question to clarify).

Comment: "I need to reach SERVER-A from the CLIENT with SCP."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SSH port forwarding can be used in this case, but you can also get warnings about invalid or incorrect host keys when attempting this.  Some SSH clients like OpenSSH track SSH host keys by domain or IP only and don't include the port number with it.  PuTTY appears to record the port number with the host key and should not suffer from this problem as long as your consistent with which port numbers you use for each host.  I'd recommend adding the port forwardings to a saved session in PuTTY.  You can then also save the additional sessions for the various remote hosts as saved sessions and use that with pscp/psftp.  You can start with any high number port for the forwarding such as 2220 and go up by one from there for each host you need to forward through an intermediate host.  Add to the saved session for `intermediate` local port forwards like port `2220` and destination `remote1:22` and port `2221` with destination `remote2:22` for remote hosts `remote1` and `remote2`  Then create sessions for `remote1` with destination `localhost` and SSH port `2220` and a session for `remote2` with destination `localhost` and SSH port `2221`.  To use sessions with pcsp/psftp use `@session-name` for the host.

The problem occurs when either you have somehow associated a SSH host key with localhost and you attempt to connect to a local port that's being forwarded to a different computer.  With OpenSSH, I fixed this problem by using `HostKeyAlias`.  I added entries to my `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host intermediate
HostName intermediate.example.org
LocalForward 2220 remote1.example.org:22
LocalForward 2222 remote2.example.org:22

Host remote1
HostName localhost
Port 2220
HostKeyAlias remote1.example.org

Host remote2
HostName localhost
Port 2221
HostKeyAlias remote2.example.org
```

My preferred fix, though, was when I deployed IPv6 on my home and work network and I no longer had to worry about connecting to an intermediate server first to get to my final destination.

Comment: Thank you both, penguin359 and Gilles for the answers. I'll look into implementing them ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

I add to the `.ssh/config` such definition:

```
Host SERVER-A
    ProxyCommand ssh SERVER-B nc -q0 %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

and then just use `ssh` or `scp` in normal way:

```
ssh user@SERVER-A
```

or

```
scp file.tar.gz user@SERVER-A:~
```

During setting the connection with `SERVER-A` the ssh library finds these configuration. It tells that ssh should use some proxy command to connect. The proxy commands connect with `SERVER-B` and then execute `nc` command (netcat) wich forward all output from proxy command to given server for given port, its define by `%h` and `%p` parameters.

Such construction also allow you to use key authentication. you have just copy your public from client machine on both servers: `SERVER-A` and `SERVER-B`.

Such configuration is also compatible with others application which use ssh library, for example `rsync`, `sftp` or GUI clients.

Comment: but is it safe?

Comment: @LanceBaynes Could you be more specific, please? If the connection is safe, authentication or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the intermediate machine as a proxy. Make sure it has [netcat (`nc`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) installed. Put the following lines in your `~/.ssh/config` (`foo` is a nickname for the inaccessible machine, `foo.example.com` is its name as seen from the intermediate machine, and `gateway.example.com` is the intermediate machine):

```
Host foo
HostName foo.example.com
ProxyCommand ssh gateway.example.com nc %h %p
```

Then `ssh foo` will connect (in two hops, but that's completely transparent) to the inaccessible machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH port forwarding:

```
ssh server-a -L2022:server-b:22
```

After this you will have port 2022 on client machine forwarded to port 22 of server-b. And you can connect to it with:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2022
```

Answer (score 1):

Following gelraen's answer.

You can use port forwarding pretty nicely when in conjunction with the `.ssh/config`. that is, you set a proxy command for a specific imaginary hostname which does nothing but tcp-forward through an already open tunnel:

```
Host imag
ProxyCommand socat - tcp-connect:localhost:2022
```

Then you can just use `ssh imag` to connect to server-b:22 when the tunnel is up.

[`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) is just what I used, `netcat` should do es well ;)

One nifty thing about `ProxyCommand` is that it interpolates environment variables - so... give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh server1 'ssh server2'
```

seems a little bit simpler to me. One can even copy files like this:

```
ssh server1 "ssh server2 'cat myFile'" >myFile
```

or

```
ssh server1 "ssh server2 'cat >myFile'" <myFile
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me; I don't think ssh will redirect stdin to the child process, so `ssh server1` just locks up waiting for `ssh server2` to complete

Comment: +1 It works, but I did not get any prompt.

Comment: If you want prompt you should use such command `ssh -t server1 'ssh server2'`. But these is not the answer for question. It doesn't allow you to use `scp` command.

Comment: that is weird, I do this all the time and it works. Maybe it has something to do with password versus key authentication?

Comment: @Kim I doubt. For me it also work to some moment. I suppose some default behaviour change after package upgrade.

Comment: It is working right now