# How to chain SSH?

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Common multiple SSH connections file handling issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/common-multiple-ssh-connections-file-handling-issue)

I want to reach hosts that are only indirectly accessible with SSH/SCP/SFTP.

Are there more solutions for this?
Are there any **small** and **clean** howtos for it?

E.g.:

```
SERVER-A
|
SERVER-B
|
CLIENT
```

I need to reach SERVER-A from the CLIENT with SCP.
SERVER-A is "behind" SERVER-B.